# select box using ul and li tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to insert `<img>` tag in each `<option>`, since option tag doesn't accept tags inside it,  I want make select box using `ul` and `li` with cancel icon inside each option on right side.

[Here is my jsfiddle so far](https://jsfiddle.net/PraneshSS/fhpf6tpg/)

```js
    $('.select ul li.option').click(function() {
       $(this).siblings().children().remove();
       var a= $(this).siblings().toggle();
    console.log( $(a).is(":visible"));
        $(this).siblings().append('<img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/6x16-free-application-icons/16/Delete.png" style="float:right; width:12px; height:12px;">');
       // $(this).addClass('darr');
        
    })
```

```css
.select ul li.option {
    background-color: #DEDEDE;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 0 #DEDEDE, 0px -1px 0 #DEDEDE;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0 #DEDEDE, 0px -1px 0 #DEDEDE;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0 #DEDEDE, 0px -1px 0 #DEDEDE;
}

.select ul li.option:hover {
    background-color: #B8B8B8;
}

.select ul li.option {
    z-index:1;
    padding:5px;
    display:none;
}

.select ul li:first-child {
    display:block;
}

.select ul li {
    cursor:default;
}

.rarr:after, .darr:after {
    content: ' ▼ ';
    float:left;
    padding:0 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select">
  <ul style="width:150px;">
    <li values="1" class="option">Dropdown one</li>
    <li values="2" class="option">Dropdown two</li>
    <li values="3" class="option">Dropdown three</li>
    <ul>
</div>
```

still there is problem
1) bullets occures on left when  opens.
2) cancel image does not disappear on  close .

thanks

Comment: There's an unclosed `ul` in your fiddle.

Comment: You want something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/fhpf6tpg/6/

Comment: First problem can solved usein CSS `list-style:none` and second problem is address of image. Add right address in src. See https://jsfiddle.net/fhpf6tpg/7/

Comment: like this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fhpf6tpg/12/)

Comment: THANKS . PROBLEM SORTED OUT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bullets can be eradicated by using `list-style:none` css rule.

Other than that, you have to tweak your code little bit to make it usable as per your expectation.

```
  $('.select ul li.option').click(function() {
    //use addBack to add the clicked element to the collection.
    $(this).siblings().addBack().children().remove();
    var a = $(this).siblings().toggle();
    $(this).siblings().append('<img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/6x16-free-application-icons/16/Delete.png" style="float:right; width:12px; height:12px;">');
    //prepend the clicked element to the parent UL
    $(this).parent().prepend(this);
  })
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/fhpf6tpg/9/)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the updated [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevks121/fhpf6tpg/4/)

Close of UL tag is missing

```
<div class="select">
  <ul style="width:150px;">
    <li values="1" class="option">Dropdown one</li>
    <li values="2" class="option">Dropdown two</li>
    <li values="3" class="option">Dropdown three</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

As for the bullets;

```
.select ul {
    list-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this your CSS to hide the bullets

```
.select ul {
    list-style: none;
}
```

and the problem of image that does not disappear on close, If you closed the  tag in a correct way it will be fine . you don't closed the ul , in your code

```
<ul style="width:150px;">
 <li values="1" class="option">Dropdown one</li>
 <li values="2" class="option">Dropdown two</li>
 <li values="3" class="option">Dropdown three</li>
</ul>
```

Try this :

```js
$('.select ul li.option').click(function() {
  $(this).siblings().children().remove();
  var a= $(this).siblings().toggle();
  console.log( $(a).is(":visible"));
  $(this).siblings().append('<img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/6x16-free-application-icons/16/Delete.png" style="float:right; width:12px; height:12px;">');
  // $(this).addClass('darr');

})
```

```css
.select ul{
  list-style:none;
}
.select ul li.option {
    background-color: #DEDEDE;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 0 #DEDEDE, 0px -1px 0 #DEDEDE;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0 #DEDEDE, 0px -1px 0 #DEDEDE;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0 #DEDEDE, 0px -1px 0 #DEDEDE;
}

.select ul li.option:hover {
    background-color: #B8B8B8;
}

.select ul li.option {
    z-index:1;
    padding:5px;
    display:none;
}

.select ul li:first-child {
    display:block;
}

.select ul li {
    cursor:default;
}

.rarr:after, .darr:after {
    content: ' ▼ ';
    float:left;
    padding:0 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select">
  <ul style="width:150px;">
    <li values="1" class="option">Dropdown one</li>
    <li values="2" class="option">Dropdown two</li>
    <li values="3" class="option">Dropdown three</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one:

you must add ul close tag like `</ul>`

```
<div class="select">
  <ul style="width:150px;">
    <li values="1" class="option">Dropdown one</li>
    <li values="2" class="option">Dropdown two</li>
    <li values="3" class="option">Dropdown three</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/fhpf6tpg/5/)